# React Native: шифрование

Tags: javascript, php, react-native

Я делаю проект на React Native. Бэкенд написан на php (Yii2). Мне нужно на бэкенде кодировать данные, а в приложении их декодировать.

Вопрос: какой метод шифрования можно использовать и в php и в js?

Comment: А чем HTTPS не подходит и шифрование на уровне транспорта, используя механизмы SSL сертификатов?

Comment: ssl гарантирует, что если кто то перехватит данные, он не сможет их прочитать?

Comment: Если нет ключа для дешифрования - то да.